# Is torque constant times the motor current the only way to estimate torque feedback in a servo motor?

Tags: dc-motor, current-measurement, servo, torque

Consider a torque and position tracking servo motor. [Once the motor reaches the target position (assume no external torque applied), the end effector should apply a torque which tracks the torque reference signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU24U.jpg) by comparing the torque feedback with the current torque.

> Is the product of the torque constant (\$K_t\$) with the sensed (possibly filtered to denoise) motor current the only way to estimate torque feedback in DC or AC servo motors? Although it well understood that the back EMF is related by direct proportion through the EMF constant (\$K_e\$) to the angular speed of the motor, is it possible to relate it to the applied time-varying torque in order to measure it?

Comment: "*Once the motor reaches the target position (assume under no torque condition), the end effector should apply a torque reference signal*" this sentence is contradictory. How do we simultaneously zero torque conditions non-zero torque conditions? Also, how is there a BEMF if the motor is just holding position (aka zero RPM).

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks for the comment. The external applied load torque is a different signal compared to the reference torque signal provided by, say, the person operating the motor. I have edited the text to reflect this meaning better by modifying the phrase you mentioned to read '*Once the motor reaches the target position (assume no external torque applied), the end effector should apply a torque which tracks the torque reference signal), the end effector should apply a torque reference signal*'.

Comment: It seems some context is missing when you are start talking about end effectors. Are you talking about a robotic arm squeezing something? And by no external torque you really mean that the only force being applied on the motor is the compressive strength of the object being grasped rather than an active force being applied? There's really no difference between the two from the perspective of the motor.

Comment: @DKNguyen I agree that some context is missing. I appreciate your help in clarifying. Consider an [earth mover](https://www.thebalancesmb.com/thmb/HY_ZFtA0i4X6MQ__VdsWpc05bx8=/853x640/smart/filters:no_upscale()/escavation-921233_960_720-57a2715c3df78c327648cd18.jpg) end effector. The expectation is that the end effector angular position should not be deflected under a load lower than the reference tracking torque.

Comment: In any case, if the motor is just holding position I don't think you can use the difference between no-load RPM as per the applied voltage and actual RPM as per the BEMF since there is no RPM unless the gearing is high enough that the motor actually spins while the output of the gearbox moves within positioning tolerances. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @DKNguyen indeed I am not sure if this is what happens in the earth moving equipment, for instance, but [here is a schematic indicating the reference and feedback signals we discussed](https://imgur.com/sBfxXfU).

Comment: I thought Earth movers were hydraulic? But if they were hydraulic using electric motors rather than an engine, I suppose they could have a small hydraulic relief so that they slowly relieve the pressure which the motor has to very slightly continuously work against? Because you could use that RPM to estimate the load in a static position.

Comment: @DKNguyen the earth mover was mentioned only as an example. (1/3)

Comment: @DKNguyen as in [the schematic](https://imgur.com/sBfxXfU), the question is about the [torque mode control](https://www.motioncontroltips.com/whats-the-difference-between-torque-mode-and-velocity-mode-in-servo-control/). (2/3)

Comment: @DKNguyen the question is targeting the controller in the linked document, in which it is mentioned that '*In torque mode (also referred to as current mode), the current loop controls the motor’s behavior. Since torque is directly proportional to current, the servo controller obtains the actual motor current from the servo drive and uses this to determine actual motor torque. It then compares the actual torque value with the desired torque and adjusts the current delivered to the motor to achieve the desired torque.*'.